# jsforce bulk load update insert '' values

Tags: node.js, jsforce

I'm trying to clear some values while doing a bulk update with jsforce.

I'm getting the values back from MySQL as ''.

So in JS '' `!== null`. This does not clear the respective value in SF.

I found Ref: https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/pull/81/files which is a bug fix to clear out the value if it's equal to `null`.

So, iterating over all my values and re-assigning '' to Null would do the trick. However, I was hoping there was another option. Any ideas? Thanks!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to NULL a value in Salesforce that was previously NOT NULL update the value to #N/A.
An empty string ('') is not sufficient.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328822&type=1&mode=1